# Authorization c# mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I want to create c# mvc internet application that allows users to edit their own accounts. I want to have fields such as first name, surname, date of birth and location.

I'm aware of the built in authorization and the Authorize attribute for the controllers. I do currently have the default AccountController in the project.

I'm just not sure what the best way is to extend on the default username and password properties for each user? Should I store the membership id in a new class containing the other properties or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You have two basic options assuming you're using MVC4 with SimpleMembership (which is the default).

1) You can extend the User table, as Bastaspast explains.  This is not a bad route for a small to medium app.

2) You can create a separate UserProfile table, and link it to your User table via it's UserId.  This seperates Membership (username, password management) from Profile (name, age, etc..).

I prefer option 2, but many people like the simplicity of option 1.  The choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

No You did not requires to create a new table with membership id mapping. Asp.Net MVC provides the methods by with you can fetch all the user's information stored in Database. You can get the record by using the User manager class of ASP.net Membership.  See example:

```
            var _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_dbContext));
            UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_dbContext);

            var user = userManager.FindById(userId);

            user.FirstName ="Update the name";

            var result = store.UpdateAsync(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the built-in lightweight SimpleMembership authorization. It will automatically provide the Asp.NET membership tables and a specific UserProfile table to store other relevant user properties.

This comes out of the box with the MVC 4 internet application template from Visual Studio

I suggest the following:

```
private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
private static object _initializerLock = new object();
private static bool _isInitialized;

protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

    LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
}

public class SimpleMembershipInitializer
{
    public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
    {
        using (var context = new UsersContext())
            context.UserProfiles.Find(1);

        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
    }
}
```

This is to initialize the simplemembership authorization on your internet application from application_start method in your global.asax.

As you can see the table/class that is used to store the relevant user information is called "UserProfile" by default. Just change the "UserProfile" (account models) class through Entity Framework code first and it will automatically adjust your data model.

Example given:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    //other relevant properties
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set;}
    public Gender Gender { get; set;}
    //etc
}
```

I hope this information can point you in the right direction. If you have any remarks, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create ActionFilter Attribute and cheked Edit userprofile ID is match with

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question